# MySQL Select query recordset in an 2d PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to fetch the record set in an PHP array. My select query is as below…......

```
SELECT sub_activity_alias
     , a_s_month
     , a_s_target
     , a_s_target_no
     , a_s_budjet
     , achieved
     , achieved_no
     , expense
     , a_s_target_type  
  FROM activity_planning 
 WHERE prj_id = 37 
   AND holder_id = 5 
   AND impl_1id = 0 
   AND impl_2id = 0 
   AND activity_id = 14 
   AND sub_activity_id = 109 
   AND acct_year = '2015-2016' 
 ORDER 
    BY FIELD(a_s_month,'Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar') ASC
```

When I run the query I am getting many rows with 9 column. I want an PHP  2d array where data will be stored.  I want this php array data in my  programming.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you do not know how to handle arrays then the answers here would not help you. Better start with the basics.

Comment: Showing the query code isn't really relevant; you could ask the same question for any SQL query. But what you do need to show is the PHP code that you've got a problem with -- what does your PHP code look like? What problem are you having with it? What have you tried doing so far to fix it?

Comment: (Although this table shows distinct room for improvement)

Answer (score 0):

First read this article carefully. http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Especially "Connect to MySQL" part. After that you will really understand the concept of MySQL and PHP relation.

Then start learning PHP basics. If you don't know what an array or control statements are, you don't know enough.

Answer (score 0):

Today I want to share you important topics that is mostly required while coding in PHP and MySQL.  One important thing that we should keep in mind so that less hitting the database, it would increase the better performance of our web software applications. Unwanted access of database is harmful and resource misuse.  If a record set of a select query is being used many time then we should keep in buffer it should be an array.

Please see the record set below. I want this in an php array so that I can use it as many time as I want without touching the database.

The select query is as below  along with the code required.

```
<?php
/****  CONNECT TO THE DATABASE *****/
$host = "localhost"; $user= "root";  $pwd = "root1";
$dblink = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pwd);
if (!$dblink)
  {
    header("Location: db_error.php");
   }

$database = "cinindia_ciiss";
mysql_select_db($database, $dblink) or die("\n Could not select database, Please try after some time..");     


/****  WRITE YOUR SQL QUERY *******/                            
$select = "SELECT sub_activity_alias, 
a_s_month, 
a_s_target, 
a_s_target_no, 
a_s_budjet, 
achieved, 
achieved_no, 
expense, 
a_s_target_type 
FROM activity_planning 
WHERE prj_id = 37 
AND holder_id = 5 
AND impl_1id = 0 
AND impl_2id = 0 
AND activity_id = 14 
AND sub_activity_id = 109 
AND acct_year = '2015-2016' 
ORDER BY FIELD(a_s_month,'Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar') ASC";
$queryResult= mysql_query($select);

/****** DECLARE YOUR ARRAY WHERE YOU WILL KEEP YOUR RECORD SETS  *******/
$data_array=array();

/******* STORE ALL THE RECORD SETS IN THAT ARRAY   ********/
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryResult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
      array_push($data_array,$row);
}


mysql_free_result($queryResult);


/******  TEST TO SEE THE RESULT OF THE ARRAY ******/
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data_array);
echo '</pre>'; 

// FREE THE ARRAY DECLAREd WHEN USING COMPLETE .

mysql_close($dblink);
?>
```

Hope it will help you. If it help, please share in in social sites from, it is at the beginning  of the topics. 
Thanks.

Comment: If you want you can see the URL Link as below.  http://learning.org.in/tutorial/php/php-array/select-query-in-a-2d-php.html